# Install NuGet package programmatically

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to install a simple nuget-package programatically. I have created a package with a Site.css file in it. So it resides in the content folder of the package.

Using this code

```
public void TestInstall(string packageID, string physicalPath)
{
   var rep = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(new PackageSource("http://nuget.testserver.lan/nuget", "Default"));

   var packagemgr = new PackageManager(
                rep,
                new DefaultPackagePathResolver("http://nuget.testserver.lan/nuget"),
                    new PhysicalFileSystem(physicalPath)
                    );

   var package = rep.FindPackagesById(packageID).First();

   packagemgr.InstallPackage(package, false);
}
```

Lets say I provide packageID = 'Testpackage' and physicalPath = 'c:\inetpub\test' it creates:

c:\Inetpub\test\Testpackage

and that folder contains:

the content folder with the Site.css AND the Testpackage.0.1.nupkg

Not quite what I'm trying to do but sort of :)

Is it possible to change it so:

- I can specify where it should place the package for its cache-functionality
- Make it place whatever resides in the content folder to the specified path?
- If the package contains dll's in the lib-folder have them go in the bin-directory (create if not exist)

Comment: Unfortunately the direct PackageManager API isn't that flexible. But you can take a look at what it does internally and change the  behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the functionality of NuGet currently relies on Visual Studio automation, so outside of VS it's difficult to get all of the same behaviour.

Lot of people have asked for functionality that would require changes from using VS automation, so I suspect it's probably on the roadmap, as it's significant work, I don't think it will be soon.

Don't forget you can install packages in the Visual Package Manager console, so it's only a single command (`Install-Package MarkdownHelper`) and doesn't require clicking through the UI.

Comment: That's actually not true. The Core API is in no way tied to VS, it's just that the VS client has the richest implementation.

Comment: @dfowler Maybe I worded it badly. What I meant was that some of the functionality (like adding references to the project, and any PS scripts that manipulate the project/solution) will only work from within VS. Or at least, that was my understanding?